# Create temp file and get file with axios in React and show download pop up

Tags: reactjs, express, axios, fs

In my app I have a situation that must create a binary file with custom extension and then send it to client. client request with `axios` and then on server create a file on fly(in tmp for example):

In Express i have method like this :

```
router.post('/send-some-file',(req,res)=>{
const {id} = req.body
/*
* Some code for getting information from db is here
*/
const fileName = "myfile.myextension"
const filePath = path.join(__dirname+`../${fileName}`)
fs.writeFile(filePath,"Data From Database",err=>{
    if(!err){
        //send file to client 'axios' , I use res.download
        res.download(filePath,err=>{})
    }   
 } 
})
```

this code is my server code that create file and send it the problem of this code is I can't know when the file is completely downloaded for removing file.

in `React` with redux I dispatch an action and call this method of with `axios`

```
axios.post('some-url/send-some-file','my id',config()).then(res => {}).catch(er=>{})
```

know i want to browser download file or give a way to user to download file in my extension format that i described.

and the response is like this , the header is : 
but I don't know how to pop up window for download or how to browser automatically download file

[image: Header Image]

Answer (score 2):

can you try this

```
 axios.post('some-url/send-some-file','my id',config()).then(res => 
{
    const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([res.data]));
    const link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = url;
    link.setAttribute('download', 'file.pdf');
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
}).catch(er=>{})
```